# UIActivityIndicator does not show/hide based on the loading of the UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I want to load a URL on a UIViewController with an UIWebView and UIActivityIndicatorView, but UIActivityIndicator never appears and UIWebView never loads the URL.

This is my code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.title = @"Web";

    [self displayURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"(Website)"]];
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [self.loadView stopAnimating];
   self.loadView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void) displayURL:(NSURL *) aURL {
    self.web.delegate = self;

    self.loadView.hidden = NO;
    [self.loadView startAnimating];

    [self.web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your webView by code, you need add

```
[self.view addSubview: web];
```

after you created webView, and of course you need to add UIActivityIndicatorView as a subView of webView or superView, so you need to add `[web addSubview: loadView]` or `[self.view insertSubview: loadView aboveSubview: web];`.

And about the URL, if your website URL is like www.google.com, you need to change @"(Website)" to the real URL. If your website is a file copied in your project, you need to change `[NSURL URLWithString: ];` to `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSBundle mainBundle][pathForResource: ofType:]];`.

Comment: Just in case this is being built against iOS 9, you're going to want to make sure that the URL you are using is secured via SSL (e.g. 'https://www.google.com' and not 'http://www.google.com'). Otherwise nothing will load and iOS will complain.
Another option would of course be to disable Application Transport Security for the URL or everything. But I just wanted to add this to be aware about it :)

Comment: I really dont need to add webView because i have a .xib file with webView and UIActivityIndicator and " (website)" isnt on my code, the URL is the Apple Developer Program URL. Thanks u for the answer but i still have the same problem, anything happens when i start the app with webViewController

Comment: Thanks for your help, i dont know whats the problem with my code

Answer (score 0):

Really poorly formulated question.

- UIWebViewController does not work
  UIWebViewController does not exists, you are talking about a UIWebView in a UIViewController
- Code is very incomplete